# Button to add an input box and accessing collections of inputs in controllers?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, frontend, inputbox

I'm a form noob and want to know how to create a collection of text-input boxes, along with a button that will allow users to add another input to this collection.

Can this be done purely with ruby and rails?  If so, how do I access the individual inputs from the group when doing stuff in the controller?  How do I identify each?  How can I tell the size of the collection/how many inputs there are?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can the solutione include the jQuery js library?

Comment: using jQuery can really be easy solution for this.

Comment: I suppose since that's pretty standard right?  Though I don't know JS, any solution is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trivial, unstyled example of the front-end portion:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="addBtn" value="Add"/>
<div id='inputs'>
</div>
```

Javascript with jQuery:

```
var nextId = 0;

$("#addBtn").on("click",function(){
    $("#inputs").append("<input type='text' id='text_"+nextId+"'/>");
    nextId++;
});
```

The inputs have unique, sequential ids. At any given time, the count is available either from `nextId` or `$(".dynInput").length`

http://jsfiddle.net/5mHTh/1/

Comment: Can my controllers view those values?

Comment: Also, I know this is probably something I can find elsewhere, but can anyone tell me where I place this js?  In tags in the html?

Comment: Sorry to bug you with questions, but will I need to have a JS post/get request to pass JS variables?  Specifically I would need nextId, then I can access the values from the params hash.

Comment: You might be able to do without it - can't Rails iterate through params based on a naming pattern? Grab all of the text_* inputs? (I've never used Rails, so I'm no help there). Failing that, however, instead of keeping the count in a JS variable, you could keep it in a hidden input, so it's included in the submited params.

Comment: The hidden input sounds like it should work.  Thank you!